# Error connecting to SQL Server instance using JRuby and Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jruby

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server 2012 database using JRuby 1.9.3 and MS JDBC Driver 4.0.  From the JRuby IRB console I'm entering the following:

```
require "sqljdbc4.jar"
Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url = "jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress;databaseName=databasename"
c = java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url, "username", "password")
```

It seems to work fine until the final line at which point I get a "Java:JavaSql::SqlException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://ipaddress;databaseName=databasename" error.

I know the ip address, database name, user name and password are correct as I can connect through SQL server management studio from the same machine without problem.

What am I missing?

edit: Tried this on Windows Server 2008 with SQL Server 2012 and Windows 7 with SQL Server 2008 Express with same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fought the same issue with JRuby 1.9.3 and MS JDBC Driver 4.0 and resolved it like this:

```
driver = Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.new
props = java.util.Properties.new
props.setProperty("user", "username")
props.setProperty("password", "password")
url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://servername;instanceName=instance;databaseName=DbName;'
conn = driver.connect(url, props)
```

Found at bottom of page here: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JDBC

It seems that my setup has issues with dynamically loading drivers and requires this more explicit approach.

Comment: I completely forgot I'd asked this.  I left it for a while and when I came back I tried this and it worked.  Annoyingly I remember seeing it originally but not realising it was any different to other examples I found.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't load the JDBC driver in the correct place that JRuby is looking for it.  By default, the require looks in C:\jruby-1.7.10\lib\

Also, you might need to add the folder where the jar file lives to the classpath.

```
require 'java'
$CLASSPATH << "your/folder"
```

My full test script looks like this:

```
$CLASSPATH << "c:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/"
require "sqljdbc4.jar"

Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
url = 'jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1\\SQL2012:1433;databaseName=TestAllTheThings'
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.get_connection(url, "sa", "sapassword")
statement = conn.create_statement

q = "SELECT * FROM Input"
rs = statement.execute_query(q)

while (rs.next) do
  puts rs.getObject('Id')
end

statement.close
conn.close
```

TestAllTheThings is my database name, Input is a table in that database, and Id is a column in that table.

Comment: Surely the fact that the "require "sqljdbc4.jar"" line runs correctly means that it can find the driver?  If I don't do that then "Java::com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" line fails too.  Putting the .jar file in the lib directory didn't change anything anyway unfortunately.

Comment: unfortunately that didn't have any effect that I can see.

Comment: If you open a command prompt, open jirb, and type `require 'sqljdbc4.jar'`, what does that return?

Comment: I was able to successfully connect and query my SQL Server 2012 instance with updated answer script.

Comment: I've tried that and every possible combination of connection string I can think of + tried jTDS with exactly the same results.  Makes no sense.